# Reutilizar plantilla de dashboard en php

Tags: php, html5

Estimados tengo una plantilla en html que uso como dashboard y lo tengo en varios formularios, quería saber como puedo tenerlo en un archivo .html y poder reutilizarlo cosa de que cuando lo modifique una vez se cambie en todo los archivos y no tenga que cambiarla cada vez en cada pagina ya que lo hace poco mantenible, estoy usando html y php.

este es el codigo del dashboard

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <div style="margin-top: 50px";></div>
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">

            <li class="active"><a href="Index.php">Ingreso de Visitas</a></li>
            <li ><a href="ListaRegistroActivo.php">Registrar Salida <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="VisitaSalida.php">Lista de Salida</a></li>

            <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Components">
                <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseComponents" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
                    <span class="nav-link-text">Reportes</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="collapseComponents">
                    <li>
                        <a href="../Reportes/ReporteDiario.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">&nbsp;</i>Diario</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../Reportes/PorRangoFecha.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass" >&nbsp;</span>Por  Fecha</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Saludos amigos y gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En PHP, usa `require`, ejem:

```
<body>
Otros html
...
<?php
require("mi_otra_pagina.php");
require("mi_otra_pagina_html.html");
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, también use include e igual me funco